# Second AJAX call not functioning

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

**Last Update**

I realized why I was getting undefined when I created the result2 variable I set it to undefined instead of `let result2 = '';` setting it to a string. Once I made that adjustment the undefined went away. Final script.js is below.

[image: last update]

**Update 4**

It finally works it came down to the following line which was incorrect `document.querySelectorAll("weathers").innerHTML = result2;` I had to go back and change *weathers* to an *id* and not a *class* and I had to change the line above to `document.querySelector("#weathers").innerHTML += result2;` and now it works. I just have to figure out on my own why I get an undefined in my code see image.

[image: 5th image]

**Update 3**

I am down to my last portion which is I get the results I want if I console log my results which look like this:

[image: 4th image]

With this line I am not getting anything in my html `document.querySelectorAll("weathers").innerHTML = result2;` I am going to try something else to see if I could get this to work. If you notice though I am getting an undefined in my code in the image does anyone know if that impacts why I am not getting any output? I get no error messages either.

**UPDATE 2**

I made the adjustments to eliminate too much code the updates code will just be in my script.js file listed below. I get the following output which is an array of objects:

[image: third image]

When I run the code I get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>       at XMLHttpRequest.xhr2.onload (script.js:57) xhr2.onload @ script.js:57 load (async) loadWeathers @ script.js:33

I am going to work on the correct syntax to extract the information I need since it is now an array of objects and not just an object.

**UPDATE 1**

With a suggestion below I was able to finally get something to work off of. Now I can see that instead of giving me one city at a time it is putting all of the cities inside of the api request url and I get the following error message:

> script.js:77 GET
>   http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=San_Francisco,Miami,New_Orleans,Chicago,New_York_City&APPID=XXXXXXXX
>   404 (Not Found)

**Background:**

I am learning about API's and am building a mini weather web app. I am learning the long way Vanilla Javascript before I move onto doing the same thing in Jquery.

**Goal:**

I would like to have two things going on at once:

1. When a user inputs a name of a city a card will pop up with weather information.
2. When a user visits the page there will be already about five major cities populated on the page like so:

[image: first]

**What I have so far:**

So far I have been able to build the functionality for the input so when a user inputs the name of the city a card will pop up on the page and looks like this:

[image: second image]

I also have some code to get into the next topic which is my problem.

**Problem:**

I have added a second ajax call that contains an array of cities that will be added to the URL. I have added a second button ("Get Weathers") for testing purposes that when I click on the button all of the cities will pop up like in the first image. I have done some research but everything I find involves jquery and not vanilla javascript Ajax. I cannot figure out why nothing is populating. I have checked the console for errors and I am not getting any. When I check the network traffic I am not getting any call requests. I am not getting anything and I cannot figure out why.

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="style.css" TYPE="text/css">
    <title>Current Weather App</title>
</head>

<body>


    <main role="main">

        <section class="jumbotron text-center">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Today's Weather</h1>
                <p class="lead text-muted">Curious about weather in your location? Just fill in below and submit.</p>
                <p>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="buttonW" type="button">Get Weather</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="buttonW2" type="button">Get Weathers</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </p>
            </div>
        </section>


        <div id="weather"></div>

        <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="row" id="weathers"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </main>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my **FINAL** script.js file:

```
    // Create an event listener
 document.getElementById("buttonW").addEventListener("click", loadWeather);
 document.getElementById("buttonW2").addEventListener("click", loadWeathers);

 ///////////////THIS IS PART OF THE loadWeathers///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 function getCity(locations) {

   for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

   }
   return locations;
 }


 function loadWeathers() {
   let xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
   const cities = [
     "5368361",
     "4173495",
     "4335045",
     "4887398",
     "5128638"
   ];
   const base_path2 =

     "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=" + getCity(cities) + "&APPID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";



   xhr2.open("GET", base_path2, true);

   xhr2.onload = function () {

     if (this.status == 200) {
       let cityWeathers2;
       try {
         cityWeathers2 = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       } catch (e) {
         // JSON not valid, show error message
       }
       console.log(cityWeathers2)


       //      //add weather info
       for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {

         let result2 = '';



         result2 +=
           `<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">${cityWeathers2.list[i].name}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Here are some weather details for your City</p>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Weather: ${cityWeathers2.list[i].weather[0].main} <img class="card-img-top weather-icon" src="${getIconURL(cityWeathers2.list[i].weather[0].icon)}" alt="Card image cap"></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Temperature: ${convertKtoF(cityWeathers2.list[i].main.temp) }&deg; </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Wind Speed: ${convertMPStoMPH(cityWeathers2.list[i].wind.speed) } </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Geo Location: ${cityWeathers2.list[i].coord.lat} , ${cityWeathers2.list[i].coord.lon}</li>
                  </ul>
             </div>`

         //  console.log(result2)


         document.querySelector("#weathers").innerHTML += result2;
       }
     }

   }

   xhr2.send();

 }


 function loadWeather() {
   // console.log(city);
   let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

   const city = document.getElementById("city").value;
   const base_path =
     "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&APPID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";





   xhr.open("GET", base_path, true);



   xhr.onload = function () {
     //   const city = document.getElementById("city").value;

     if (this.status == 200) {
       let cityWeathers;
       try {
         cityWeathers = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       } catch (e) {
         // JSON not valid, show error message
       }



       const result =

         `<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">${cityWeathers.name}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Here are some weather details for your City</p>
              </div>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">Weather: ${cityWeathers.weather[0].main} <img class="card-img-top weather-icon" src="${getIconURL(cityWeathers.weather[0].icon)}" alt="Card image cap"></li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Temperature: ${convertKtoF(cityWeathers.main.temp) }&deg; </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Wind Speed: ${convertMPStoMPH(cityWeathers.wind.speed) } </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Geo Location: ${cityWeathers.coord.lat} , ${cityWeathers.coord.lon}</li>
              </ul>
         </div>`;


       document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML = result;
     }

   }



   xhr.send();

 }


 // Convert from Kelvins to Fahrenheit
 function convertKtoF(kelvin) {
   return Math.round((kelvin - 273.15) * 1.8);
 }

 // Convert from Meters Per Second to Miles Per Hour
 function convertMPStoMPH(mps) {
   return (Math.round(10 * mps * 2.2369362920544) / 10) + " mph";
 }
 // Weather icon
 function getIconURL(icon) {
   return "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png";
 }
```

***Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!***

Comment: At that part I just want it to plug in the cities that are in the cities array.

Comment: Starting at the top, are you saying you click the _"Get Weathers"_ button and you don't even get an AJAX request happening? And there's no errors in your browser console? How are you monitoring network traffic?

Comment: Running your code, I get a 404 response from the API with a _"city not found"_ message. You should ideally [consult the API documentation](https://openweathermap.org/current) for the correct query syntax to use and also add an [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onerror) handler to your `XmlHTTPRequest` objects

Comment: Yes when I click the button nothing is happening. If I take that code completely out and just run the first button it works it will make a card pop up like in the second image above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't speak to the accuracy of the request (per comments), but the problem is `xhr2.send();` is within the body of your `xhr2.onload` function.

For multiple cities, you may need to use city Ids, see https://openweathermap.org/current#severalid. The docs don't seem to mention multiple cities by name as you are attempting to do.

Comment: Thank you I will update above what I am now getting.

Comment: @JermaineSubia I added some additional info

Comment: I am testing it out.

Comment: added my update above I feel like it is almost there thank you so much.

Comment: You just need to update how the `result2` html is being generated now since the response is different; but this has really deviated from the initial question

Comment: I saw that I adjusted to class but I need to figure out the correct syntax to target the date I need for example cityWeathers2[i].name does not work so need to figure this out.

Comment: `cityWeathers2.list[i].name`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201181/discussion-between-jermaine-subia-and-anthony).